# 使った「日語」はいつからですか？

Tags: words, etymology

語は「日本語」とは今日、人が使う語なんです。

だけど、とっくに「日語」とは人が使った語そう。

そうなんで、知りたいいつが「日本語」が使わなくて「日語」が使いました？

Comment: I always thought 日語 (ri yu) was a Chinese word...

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/%E6%97%A5%E8%AA%9E

Comment: So.. by とっくに「日語」とは人が使った語そう do you mean it's probably old-fashioned / archaic, or maybe obsolete?

Comment: I would like to answer your question sincerely. To my regret, it is very difficult to interpret your question written in Japanese.  So, I appreciate a lot if you would additionally post the question in English.

Comment: In my broken Japanese I'm asking WHEN 日語 was used and not 日本語.

Comment: Plz answer in the nihongos to help me learnz! :D

Comment: 日語 is an obsolete word, so unless you're reading some old-fashioned text the answer is "never".

Comment: @Blavius But if it's old-fashioned and obsolete, then the answer should be like "around 19XX", or "in XX Era" etc., no?

Comment: @Chocolate You're right, I misread the question. I thought it was asking when to use 日語 vs 日本語.

Comment: Jisho.org is not a reliable resource.  They pull data from various sources including Wikipedia, and content that is technically correct -- like 日語 meaning "Japanese" -- winds up presented on the Jisho.org site without the proper context, and thus essentially incorrect (or at least misleading) -- like the fact that 日語 is only used in Chinese (and rarely Korean) contexts, and not in Japanese.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

日本語では「日本語」のことを「日語」とは言いません。「日語」は中国語で言う日本語のことです。

Comment: 上の方{かた}のおっしゃる通り、です。 ちなみに、韓国からでも「日本語(일본어)」を約して「日語(일어)」とも言います。 **Reference** http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%97%A5%E8%AA%9E